# classnotfoundexception error in java when running a JFrame?

Tags: java

I am working on windows application in java:

I just test a button that make function login in my system:

My button action performed code:

```
private void loginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    if(emp.isSelected()) // get the selected radio button
    {
        Account a = new Account();
        Emp e = new Emp();
        a.setUsername(username.getText().toUpperCase());
        a.setPassword(password.getText().toUpperCase());
        e.login(a);
        this.dispose();
    }

    else if(supp.isSelected())
    {
    }

    else if(admin.isSelected())
    {
        Account a = new Account();
        Admin m = new Admin();
        a.setUsername(username.getText().toUpperCase());
        a.setPassword(password.getText().toUpperCase());
        m.login(a);
        this.dispose();
    }

    else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select a choice", "Alert", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

The function login code:

```
public class Emp
{

public void login(Account a)
{
    boolean find = false;
    ObjectInputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\فاطمة\\Downloads\\employees.bin"));
        ArrayList<Account> b = (ArrayList)in.readObject();
        Iterator<Account> i = b.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext())
        {
            Account ac = i.next();
            if(ac.getUsername().equals(a.getUsername()) && ac.getPassword().equals(a.getPassword()))
            {
                find = true;
            }
            else
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong username or password .. try again !!", "Login Failed",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }
        if(find)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome " + a.getUsername(), "Login Success", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                emp_page e = new emp_page();
                e.setLocation(350, 150);
                e.setSize(400, 490);
                e.setTitle("Products Management");
                e.setVisible(true);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        //Logger.getLogger(Emp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        //Logger.getLogger(Emp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //Logger.getLogger(Emp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
}
```

The account class code:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Account implements Serializable{

private String username;
private String password;

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
}
```

I have two problems:

First: when i click button login ... the program terminates without doing anything.
Second: another error occurred when running my code: it throws an error says:

```
 java.lang.classnotfoundexception: Account
```

notes: the code is working good when running it in the default package but these problems occur when i moved it to a specific package ... i make refactoring and everything is good but still same problem... i try to create new project and writing the code again but still same problem.

I am sorry for long post but please someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: All the class are in the same package?

Comment: @Abdelhak yes sir, all classes are in the same package ... i wonder why it is not working... code is perfect.

Comment: Just one thing try to post the package explorer in eclipse maybe a picture

Comment: Sorry I do as possible to do

Comment: @Abdelhak np sir, thanks for you trying to help :)